# gcc complains about both %lu and %u

Tags: gcc, printf

If I try to compile

```
printf("here %u\n", dest->q_head);
```

gcc complains with

```
error: format ‘%u’ expects argument of type ‘unsigned int’, but argument 2 has type ‘ngx_uint_t {aka long unsigned int}’
```

fair enough..

But if I compile with

```
printf("here %lu\n", dest->q_head);
```

I get

```
error: format ‘%lu’ expects argument of type ‘long unsigned int’, but argument 2 has type ‘ngx_uint_t {aka unsigned int}’
```

Nothing else in the code changes.

ngx_uint_t is defined as...

```
typedef unsigned int    ngx_uint_t;
```

dest->head is defined as...

```
ngx_uint_t                  q_head;
```

If I cast it to (unsigned int) it compiles and prints OK.

```
printf("here %u \n", (unsigned int)dest->q_head);
```

Any idea what is going on there?

Comment: [Can't reproduce](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/da1544e7ecaa4231) -  [mcve] needed.

Answer (score 0):

the implementation of `printf()` does not know the term `ngx_uint_t`, the `typedef` does not change this. so`printf()` simply does not know what is going on and throws errors

http://code.metager.de/source/xref/gnu/glibc/stdio-common/vfprintf.c from line 270 downwards

( http://code.metager.de/source/xref/gnu/glibc/stdio-common/printf.c `printf()` calls `vfprintf()` )

this is also the reason why it works when casted

Comment: I don't follow: I tried reading the code.
I thought the problem is with GCC validating the format string, no?  I The error is compiling rather than running the code.  The error messages implies GCC has some opinion of what ngx_uint_t is since it reports it, albeit incorrectly.
Is printf implemented as a library or as some kind of template/macro?

Comment: printf is in `libc` if you want to figure this out exactly use `gdb`....

Comment: GCC errors are compilation problems, you can't use gdb on code that has not compiled :)